# PHP: $_SESSION never getting set, but $_POST is ?

Tags: php, session, superglobals

[@the downvote and idiot remarks, that's not cool to beat up on people. I rechecked the documentation and coursenotes for 3 whole days before even asking the question - .
Closing this to prevent a chorus of idiots piling on with useless and factually incorrect comments, as James did. Thanks to Charles and Brent B for being very helpful.
This turns out not to be a Safari issue so I removed those tags.]

---

$_SESSION is not getting set in Safari, and hence my multipage form breaks.
$_POST, $_REQUEST do get set (but obviously disappear on subsequent pages).
Versions are PHP: 5.3.1, Safari 5.

Help! It is **not** an issue with any of the following, I checked them all, and I read all the other related questions:

- session_start() works. SID/PHPSESSID is preserved across pages.
- session.use_cookies = 1, session.use_only_cookies = 1
- I checked *php.ini* and believe it to be ok
- I did configure Safari to accept All cookies (for now). No difference.
- I can manually set *$_SESSION['debug']* and that **does** get preserved across pages (and the session file is correctly written out). Unless I do that, *$_SESSION* never gets defined.

I don't have time to debug this nonsense, so which of the following last-minute workarounds is the least ugly? (this is a programming assignment, not production code)
According to course notes , $_SESSION is supposed to merge $_POST, $_REQUEST, $_GET, session and globals right?

1. manually do *$_SESSION = array_merge($_SESSION,$_POST);* [this works]
2. use hidden form to re-post *$_POST* on subsequent forms
3. other?

(On a wider note, should PHP simply be considered broken on Safari (5)?)

Comment: Are you testing with a fully qualified domain name, an IP address, or localhost? Safari has had a *lot* of finicky problems accepting cookies from things that aren't actual domain names in the past, though I thought they'd fixed that a while ago. Also, `$_GET`/`$_POST`/`$_REQUEST` are built from submitted data, while `$_SESSION` is stored on-disk, but referred to in a cookie. No session cookie means you get an empty session.  Other than being in all capitals and starting with an underscore, these superglobals share *nothing else* in common.  Don't merge `$_POST` into `$_SESSION`, that's silly.

Comment: Yes, from localhost (how can I double-check the exact address it sees? and is that safe?) And there **is** a session cookie. _session.cookie_domain_ has no value.

Comment: For the entertainment value, try accessing the site as `127.0.0.1`, it might make a difference.  No cookie domain for your session cookie is OK here.  Also, watch the Network tab in the Developer tools.  You should be able to click on the HTTP request to the PHP script and examine the headers that are sent and received.  You should see `Set-Cookie` headers from your PHP code (done automatically), and corresponding `Cookie` headers on following requests.

Comment: If the session ID is the same then there shouldn’t be any difference in different browsers as the session is handled and stored on the server side.

Comment: Do you have the same problem in other browsers?

Comment: Stupid question but you are calling session_start() on every page and not just once to create it aren't you?

Comment: I tried referencing address as 127.0.0.1, no good. I tried  ini_set(session.cookie_domain to 'localhost', 'http://localhost', '127.0.0.1', no good. Developer tools (you mean Web Inspector right? how and where can I bring up the HTTP request?)   Yes I'm calling session_start() on every page, that is documented as being safe. Other browsers: don't have any installed, no use trying that. I think we can debug from the Session section of what phpinfo() dumps right? Do you want to see that?

Comment: Is display_errors set to on and error_level set to -1? What's in your $_COOKIES variable?

Comment: You have not tested your code in other browsers, yet you say your problem is _Safari specific_?

Comment: `According to course notes, $_SESSION is supposed to merge` LOL I wish I read these notes. Expecting more fun from it. Any chance you've got that course at April, 1? ;)

Comment: @James, as I stressed, I rechecked the documentation and coursenotes for 3 whole days, read tons of examples, and tried a ton of stuff out, before even asking the question, so what you wrote was flat wrong. In the 3 minutes it takes you to insult me, you could have actually typed something useful, or alternatively just said nothing. It's not my fault PHP has a ton of crappy superglobals and arcane merging rules - what a broken language.

Comment: @Salman, correct it's not Safari-specific - not this time. I was led by a reading of the coursenotes + documentation + reading other similar known issues here and on other Q&A sites to believe it was a Safari-specific issue (I previously did hit several Safari-specific issues - check out the keywords 'cookie', 'session', '$_SESSION'), and I quadruple-checked my code vs code known to work in IE/FF. As I already wrote yesterday, I did not have an alternative browser install available to test within the time limit.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$_SESSION does NOT merge other super global arrays, it is it's own array. $_REQUEST is a merge of $_POST and $_GET, but that's about it. From what you describe, $_SESSION is working properly. Read the official manual.
http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.variables.superglobals.php

Comment: Ok, my mistake. But on a multipage form then, is it ok then to declare a $_SESSION variable for every variable for which a single-page form would ordinarily use $_POST array? (obviously it will work in this code, but is there any downside to creating several $_SESSION variables?)

Comment: (I got confused between $_SESSION, $_REQUEST and 'EGPCS' ordering, I thought everything got merged into $_SESSION . http://www.php.net/manual/en/ini.core.php#ini.variables-order )

Comment: It would be easier to just store the $_POST in a $_SESSION variable. For example, $_SESSION['page1_post'] = $_POST. That would avoid variable name conflicts.

Comment: @smci, the "EGPCS" thing you mention is an artifact of prehistoric PHP.  There used to be a thing called `register_globals`, which caused request variables to become *actual real variables* in the global scope, instead of living in arrays.  That acronym represented the default order of how those variables were defined (or redefined).  If whatever documentation you have still references the term, I highly *highly* suggest discarding it and asking whoever gave it to you why they're relying on **historic, incorrect information** in a new course. (cont)

Comment: @smci There is only one superglobal that gets merged in modern PHP: `$_REQUEST`.  On older-ish (pre-5.3) installations, `$_REQUEST` is the combination of get, post, and cookie, in that order.  In 5.3, it was changed by default to be only get and post.  This is a configurable thing, thank goodness.  Generally having cookie in there isn't useful.

Comment: @Charles, Brent (and Col Shrapnel), thanks for all the detail. When I rechecked vs your explanation, the documentation did not in fact say this, but it sure could have been edited for improved clarity - it's a soup of superglobals.

Comment: @smci, the PHP team recently made some major organizational changes that allowed them to vastly increase the speed of documentation changes.  This, combined with the complete removal of `register_globals` in the upcoming PHP 5.4 is very likely for the change.